# Reducing a data frame based on column values for each row

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with some values. I want to sum the top 4 items in a row of 5 columns without using NumPy.

```
  a,b,c,d,e
0 2,4,0,4,1 # result 9
1 5,0,0,5,1 # result 11
n ...
9 5,4,1,5,4 # result 18
df['total'] = (df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].sum(axis=1) - df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].min(axis=1))
#Output
  a,b,c,d,e,total
0 2,4,0,4,1,9
1 5,0,0,5,1,11
n ....
9 5,4,1,5,4,18
```

I am not sure of the most accurate way to solve this problem. I considered transposing the subset of the data frame into a series, removing the smallest value and returning it to the data frame. But it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: @jazrael reopened for you. Thanks

Comment: hmm, your solution is good if not need numpy